# Threads not being cleaned up after they finish execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, tcplistener

Simple implementation of an asynchronous multithreaded TCP server.
Works as intented, except, memory usage keeps going up.
After investigating I found that that memory were all thread objects not being cleaned up.
However, the threads do write "host disconnected" to the log file, and since that's the last line of code for that thread to execute I expect it to clean up itself. But that doesn't seem to be happening. For each and every connection that is made, a thread is created and stops running but it but never completely cleans up.

What is going on?

No exceptions are being generated either.

```
    private void AcceptNextClient()
    {
        if (acceptConnections) serverSocket.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(AcceptTcpClientCallback), serverSocket);
    }


    private void AcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpListener serverSocket = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
            TcpClient clientConnection = serverSocket.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
            new Thread(unused => HandleClientCommunication(clientConnection)).Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Disk.AppendLog(ex.ToString()); }
        AcceptNextClient();
    }

    private void HandleClientCommunication(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        string hostName = "";
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream()))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream()))
            {
                hostName = Dns.GetHostEntry(((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address).HostName;
                bool read = true;
                while (read)
                {
                    string buffer = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (buffer == null) read = false;
                    else
                    {
                        if (buffer.ToUpper().Equals("CLOSE_CONNECTION")) read = false;
                        else
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(buffer);
                            sw.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
                tcpClient.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Disk.AppendLog(hostName + " " + ex.ToString());
        }
        Disk.AppendLog("host disconnected");
    }

    public static void AppendLog(string msg)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(exePath + "errors.log", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " " +  msg + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Comment: " a thread is created and stops running but it but never completely cleans up." what makes you conclude that, exactly? And do say "because the memory increased". Have you tried a memory profiler?

Comment: yes I tried JetBrains .dotTrace, and process explorer has a tab on .NET performance, .NET CLR LocksAndThreads where I can clearly see the number of thread objects going up any time a client connects. And never going back down when they disconnect. On first starting the program it is around 7MB, but after a few days it goes over 100MB and still growing. Doing a GC.Collect() doesn't clean them up either.

Comment: There's nothing shown that would keep the threads around if "host disconnected" has been written. My suspicion would be that there simply isn't any memory pressure to make it worth doing a full collect. Did you try forcing a `GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` ? Note: you shouldn't leave this in production code - it is simply to help identify whether this is the cause.

Comment: Another thing to check: do the threads return from `Disk.AppendLog`?

Comment: When I run it as a service, neither GC methods clean up the threads. I'm logging a message right before the GC and right after. If I do only GC.Collect(), both before and after get logged. If I do the other one with the waitforfinalizers, the second never gets logged.
However, if I don't run it as a service, both GC collect methods work perfectly while also cleaning up the thread objects. What on earth is going on here?
@Marc Gravell

Comment: @MaximiliaanAelvoet have you got any custom finalizers in the code? It all *looks* reasonable; hard to say much from here

Comment: None whatsoever, very few lines of codes really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer, after noticing the Garbage Collector wasn't ever able to run while the program was being run as a service but did run (and solve all memory issues) when it was running as a Form.

Removing the [STAThread] at Main(string[] args) fixed all the issues. There wasn't anything wrong with the code itself.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828988

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is if you use Thread  like this

```
new Thread(unused => HandleClientCommunication(clientConnection)).Start(); 
        }
```

and if you have let's suppose 100 calls per second you  will end up with 100 MB more at least  in your App  as each thread will require 1MB at least remember that garbage collector can not guarantee that memory will always be collected even if thread has finish the execution.
what I can suggest here is to switch all your code to use Task.
your code will look something like this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(unused => HandleClientCommunication(clientConnection)); 
        }
```

Here why  you should use task over Thread (when it's possible)

- Creating and destroying a thread is an expensive operation in terms
  of time
- Having lots of threads wastes memory resources and also hurts performance due
  to the operating system having to schedule and context switch between the runnable threads
- Tasks are scheduled on a pool of threads. The specific number of threads depends on the scheduler used.If your application makes many requests of the thread pool, the thread pool will try to service all of
  the requests using just this one thread. However, if your application is queuing up several requests
  faster than the thread pool thread can handle them, additional threads will be created.

Comment: Tried it, now the number of thread objects is going up less fast, but none the less still going up.

Comment: this is normal as you have a lot of threads that are created and you cannot control so the best approach is to try to limit the numbers of connections at the some time using the Qeue<T> class for exmple

Comment: It's not normal I'm afraid, the number of threads keep going up and remains high, eventhough all current connections have been closed.

Comment: How many Requests how many threads try  to make some statistics

Comment: There are no statistics, I'm testing it. Every request is a request I make myself. It used to be one thread for each request, now it's a bit fuzzy. It looks like as long as I keep making consistent requests the number of threads doesn't go up. However,if I wait a few seconds to make a new one. The client will hang for 1-2seconds. Followed by a new thread object being created on the server and then the client gets the response. If I put around 4 seconds between all the requests, a new thread gets created every time. If there's less time in between requests, it doesn't make another thread object